# Add ability to collapse Teams recently active questions panel

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, there was an [experiment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346137/technical-site-integration-observational-experiment-live-on-stack-overflow) that makes a few changes to the left sidebar on all Stack Overflow pages. Two variants for this change are in effect, while a third variant incorporates a large panel that showcases recently active questions on other technical sites.

[image]

I created a [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346142/622284) to add a collapse button to the panel, with a note that it would be beneficial to the Teams panels that show up in the same place.

The panels are very in-your-face, and consume a lot of space on the Home page.

My feature request was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and there is now a collapse button in the top right of the Technical Q&A Recently Active panel. As a bonus, when this page is accessed from the same browser, it will *stay collapsed* for 1 week.

[image]

However, the Teams panel was unaffected, and it was [mentioned by Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/346137/technical-site-integration-observational-experiment-live-on-stack-overflow/346142#comment1159458_346147) that a feature request should be created here, as the current purview of the experiment is limited only to the incorporation of technical Q&A access to Stack Overflow.

Could we add this collapse button to the Teams Recently Active questions panel(s) as well? Could it have the same effects that the experimental Recently Active Technical Site questions had? (Preserves the state it was last set to for 1 week when displayed on the same browser)

[image]

Comment: Nice freehand... orange arrow?

Comment: @S.S.Anne You know it. Thought about freehanding "Collapse" with a box around it but it wasn't even tastefully awful.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you let me know when you posted this. Sorry for not getting a status tag on it. Fixed now!  Thanks for asking about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this here - particularly since I recommended it. I've gotten news that this has been scheduled to be built and should be coming later this year. I'll keep this updated as things progress.

---

This is now live! Thanks to the Teams Team for getting this change out.